Why do we get overtones in a high-overtone bulk acoustic (HBAR) resonator?
In HBAR we tend to observe a base resonant frequency and then overtones at higher frequencies. Why can't we have just one standing waves in between the top and bottom electrode? What causes the overtones?

If you hit a tuning fork it also generates all kinds of harmonics in addition to the fundamental. The transducer itself is not an ideal exciter it has some energy content everywhere.
